# Visual Studio 2013 debugging error Asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When I debug my code of Asp.net web-app visual studio build and compile it successfully but doesn't start my browser automatically ..And I open my browser manually and see my output and every time I change my code the output remain same ..

Answer (score 0):

Set Default browser in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET projects:

Right click a webpage (.aspx, or on a folder)
Select Browse With...
Choose your browser
Click Set as Default
Click Browse
ASP.NET MVC 1 projects:

Right click Default.aspx, then follow steps above.

ASP.NET MVC 2 projects:

As there is no Default.aspx, you need to create a Web Form (right-click project > Add > New Item) and follow the steps above.

Comment: I have already try to done this but visual studio give another options Like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right click on your project name. Click "Properties". Your project properties should be displayed.
2. On "Web" tab of the properties, under "Start Action" group, tick "Current Page" radio button.
3. Save your settings (ctrl + s).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Note: This will open the default page of your web application. You may specifically choose a page to open by ticking "Specific Page" radio button and specify the page you want to open.